# Using custom msg in custom srv

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i have a msg package with a custom message like this:

```
MyStruct.msg
...
/* Content of MyStruct*/
HeaderStruct header
DataStruct data
```

using this msg type in different Nodes

Now i want to implement a srv using MyStruct.msg
I modified my CmakeLists.txt of my service package with:

```
find_package(my_msgs REQUIRED)
```

and added to the package.xml

```
 <build_depend>my_msgs</build_depend>
 <exec_depend>my_msgs</exec_depend>
```

In the srv file i added

```
my_msgs/MyStruct data
---
float64 result
int64 calculation_time
```

but when building i always get the error

```
AttributeError: 'ServiceSpecification' object has no attribute 'base_type'
```

as soon as switching to this

```
float64 data
---
float64 result
int64 calculation_time
```

it works ... am i missing something ? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296086/using-custom-msg-in-custom-srv/) by [bhmth](https://answers.ros.org/users/35969/bhmth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-07-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that you are missing the dependency in the `rosidl_generate_interfaces` call.

it should look like:

```
rosidl_generate_interfaces(<MY_MESSAGE_TARGET>
  "srv/MySrv.srv"
  DEPENDENCIES my_msgs
)
```

You can refer to [sensor_msgs for an example](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/1d80aae3de9b0c03052e13ec04a0c32693b38f61/sensor_msgs/CMakeLists.txt#L53=L58),

HTH

Edit:

> should definitely be mentioned here https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/About-ROS-Interfaces

I agree that this should be documented. Though, that wiki page is about the structure of the msg/srv files and doesn't make reference to the cmake code to generate them so I don't think this is the right place for it. A rosidl tutorial would be more appropriate. I started a draft at https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Rosidl-Tutorial but didnt get to finishing it and submitting the corresponding code yet.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2018-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhmth](https://answers.ros.org/users/35969/bhmth/) on 2018-07-04**:
That was the deal. Thank you very much !
should definitely be mentioned here

https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/About-ROS-Interfaces

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2018-07-04**:
If this answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted (using the checkmark) so that community members know the question has been answered successfully

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-05**:
@bhmth the page you referenced in your comment is a publically editable wiki. Please feel free to contribute to it by adding additional information where you think it would be helpful.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-10-26**:
Misspelling a type in a srv like int64 produces an error like `rosidl_parser.InvalidResourceName: int364`, misspelling std_msgs/Header results in the AttributeError, but look a few lines below for the `fatal error: std_msg/msg/header__struct.h: No such file or directory` (std_msg -> std_msgs)

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-10-26**:
Making same error in a .msg produces more helfpul message like 'Message interface ... contains an unknown field type: std_msg/Header header' (both of these are for bouncy)

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-10-26**:
In Ubuntu a 'Crash report' dialog pops up for every failed build with this type of error 'Sorry, the application rosidl_generator_c has stopped unexpectedly'.